# collision and intersection of player and squares

Tags: java, collision-detection, collision, bounds

I am making a game where a player must dodge squares that are falling from the sky.

I am trying to make it so that when the player intersects or collides with a falling square, the program will notice.

I realize that i have to get the bounds of the falling squares and the player, but i do not know how to do so. Any help is much appreciated.

Player class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;


public class Player extends JPanel { 
     private int XLocation;
     private int squareSize;
     private int YLocation ;
     private int MoveSpeed;
     int xMouse, yMouse;


public int XLocation(){
    return XLocation = 300;
}

public int YLocation(){
    return YLocation = 750;
}

public int SquareSize(){ 
    return squareSize = 20;
}  

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
    g.fillRect(XLocation,YLocation,squareSize,squareSize);
}

public Rectangle bounds(){ 
 return(new Rectangle(XLocation,YLocation,20,20));
}

public int MoveSpeed(){
    return MoveSpeed = 23;
}

 public Player(){
    XLocation();
    SquareSize();
    MoveSpeed();
    YLocation();
}


   public void PlayerMove(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){
        XLocation = evt.getX();
        YLocation = evt.getY();
   }



}
```

The rectangle class

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.util.Random;

public class Square {

private int XLocation;
private int Size;
private int YLocation = -Size;
private int fallSpeed = 1;
Random rand = new Random();



public int generateRandomXLocation(){
    return XLocation = rand.nextInt(Game.WINDOW_WIDTH - Size);
}


public int generateRandomSquareSize(){ 
    return Size = rand.nextInt((30-17)+1)+17;
}



public int generateRandomFallSpeed(){
    return fallSpeed = rand.ints(3, 3, 8).findFirst().getAsInt();
}


public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(XLocation,YLocation,Size,Size);
}


public Square(){
    generateRandomXLocation();
    generateRandomSquareSize();
    generateRandomFallSpeed();
}



public void update(){


    if(YLocation >= Game.WINDOW_HEIGHT){
        generateRandomXLocation();
        generateRandomFallSpeed();
        generateRandomSquareSize();
        YLocation = -Size;
    }

    //moves the square down if the square is inside the window
    if(YLocation <= Game.WINDOW_HEIGHT){
        YLocation += fallSpeed;
    }
}
public void GetBounds(){
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(XLocation,YLocation,Size,Size); 
} 
}
```

Game Class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Game extends JPanel { 

public static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 600;
public static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 900;


Square[] squareArray = new Square[20];

Player thePlayer = new Player();


public Game() {

    //initializes square objects
    for (int i = 0; i < squareArray.length; i++)
        squareArray[i] = new Square();


}

public void paint(Graphics graphics) {


    graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE); 
    graphics.fillRect(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    //paints square objects to the screen
    for (Square aSquareArray : squareArray) {
        aSquareArray.paint(graphics);    
    }
    thePlayer.paint(graphics); 

}

public void update() {
    for (Square aSquareArray : squareArray) aSquareArray.update();
}



  private void mouseMove(MouseEvent evt) {
      thePlayer.PlayerMove(evt);  
} 


 public void collision(){
  Rectangle rectangle1 = thePlayer.bounds(); 
  }


public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Game game = new Game();
    Player thePlayer = new Player();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Raining Multiple Squares");
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    BufferedImage cursorImg = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);


   Cursor blankCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
cursorImg, new Point(0, 0), "blank cursor");


  frame.getContentPane().setCursor(blankCursor);


          frame.addMouseMotionListener(new    java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseMoved(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
            mouseMove(evt); 
        } 

        private void mouseMove(MouseEvent evt){
            game.mouseMove(evt); 
        }
    });

    while (true) {
        game.update();
        game.repaint(); 
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
}





}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand.  You know the current `XLocation`, `YLocation`, and size, so you should be able to compute the bounds from those.  What's the problem?

Comment: I dont know how to get the bounds for my array of squares

Comment: Each `Square` has a `GetBounds` method.  Isn't this working?  Why can't you call `GetBounds` on each square in your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test collision the same way you are painting  the squares.

```
 public void collision(){
     Rectangle rectangle1 = thePlayer.bounds();//player rectangle 
     for (Square square: squareArray) {
        if(square.GetBounds().intersects(rectangle1)){//testing all squares vs player
            //if you are here a collision happened
            //you can remome square add score ...
        }  
    } 
 }
```

`intersects` method test `this` rectangle againts the rectagle you are passing to and returns true if the two rectagles are intersecting.

And don't forget to call your `collision`method once every iteration of your game loop.